# Linkedin php api not setting access token in codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, linkedin-api

This is my first time working with the linkedIn api and I am trying to follow this example in the official documentation:

```
[http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples][1]
```

I have refactored that same procedural code into a codeigniter controller class called `Auth`:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die();

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct () 
    {

      parent::__construct();

      define('API_KEY',      $this->config->item('key'));
      define('API_SECRET',   $this->config->item('secret'));
      define('REDIRECT_URI', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':8000/auth');
      define('SCOPE',        'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress rw_groups');

    }

    public function index()
    {
      var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
      if (!empty($this->session->userdata('state'))) {
        $user = $this->fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
        print "Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName.";
      } else {
        // $this->session->sess_destroy();
        echo anchor('auth/oauth', 'Sign in with Linkedin');
      }

    }


    public function oauth()
    {
      // OAuth 2 Control Flow
      if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
          // LinkedIn returned an error
          print $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
          exit;
      } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          // User authorized your application
          if ($this->session->userdata('state') == $_GET['state']) {
              // Get token so you can make API calls
              $this->getAccessToken();
          } else {
              // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
              exit;
          }
      } else { 
          if ((empty($this->session->userdata('expires_at'))) || (time() > $this->session->userdata('expires_at'))) {
              // Token has expired, clear the state
              $this->session->sess_destroy();
          }
          if (empty($this->session->userdata('access_token'))) {
              echo "here I am";
              // Start authorization process
              $this->getAuthorizationCode();
          }
      }

    }

    protected function getAccessToken() {
        $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                        'client_id' => API_KEY,
                        'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                        'code' => $_GET['code'],
                        'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
                  );

        // Access Token request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

        // Tell streams to make a POST request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                        array('http' => 
                            array('method' => 'POST',
                            )
                        )
                    );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        // Native PHP object, please
        $token = json_decode($response);

        // Store access token and expiration time

        // $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
        // $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
        // $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

        $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $token->access_token);
        $this->session->set_userdata('expires_in', $token->expires_in);
        $this->session->set_userdata('expires_at', time() + $this->session->userdata('expires_in'));

        return true;
    }

    protected function getAuthorizationCode() {
      $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
                      'client_id' => API_KEY,
                      'scope' => SCOPE,
                      'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
                      'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
                );

      // Authentication request
      $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

      // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
      // $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];
      $this->session->set_userdata('state', $params['state']);

      // Redirect user to authenticate
      redirect($url);
    }


    protected function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
        $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $this->session->userdata('access_token'),
                        'format' => 'json',
                  );

        // Need to use HTTPS
        $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                        array('http' => 
                            array('method' => $method,
                            )
                        )
                    );


        // Hocus Pocus
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        // Native PHP object, please
        return json_decode($response);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
      $_SESSION = array();
      $this->load->view('comment_index');
    }

}
```

I am using the database to store sessions and I was expecting `access_token` to be one of the values stored in my serialized field called `user_data`. But I get nothing. The output of the current session is:

```
array (size=5)
  'session_id' => string '1dfcbc17bf0346424726c7cace63501b' (length=32)
  'ip_address' => string '`127.0.0.1`' (length=9)
  'user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0' (length=81)
  'last_activity' => int 1386687134
  'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
```

I don't understand why linkedin is not giving me back tokens for storage. Because of the redirect_url, I am not able to debug this code properly either. So far what is working is:

1. User is redirected to authorization window with this ur: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75y11f289134ga&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+rw_groups&state=52a72cc4e54f36.03304050&redirect_uri=`http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fauth`
2. User is being redirected to the `auth` action without any error with this url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth?`code=AQTWPFJqnZlBZmFByb3Vbjkf4jtNvn8C7atg5iM6iXFW3ON_SrM3uJ9h8AiF1RbMjgGt_NpDq4cTPL1qw8uNiA_vsOv1H3lpxu0IxHVx_sa9rDAinbo&state=52a72d109261d4.41607693

But where is my profile data? How and where do I make an api call to retrieve profile data? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do the same in the Codeigniter.

Here is procedure to get Auth User Profile.

1. Create a library for Linkedin

   ```
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   /**
    * CodeIgniter Linked API Class
    *
    *
    * @package         CodeIgniter
    * @subpackage      Libraries
    * @category        Libraries
    * @author          Muhamamd Hafeez
    */
   class Linkedin {

       function __construct(){

       }

       public function getAuthorizationCode() {
           $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
               'client_id' => API_KEY,
               'scope' => SCOPE,
               'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
               'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
           );
           // Authentication request
           $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

           // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
           $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

           // Redirect user to authenticate
           header("Location: $url");
           exit;
       }

        public function getAccessToken() {
           $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
               'client_id' => API_KEY,
               'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
               'code' => $_GET['code'],
               'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
           );
           // Access Token request
           $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

           // Tell streams to make a POST request
           $context = stream_context_create(
                   array('http' =>
                       array('method' => 'POST',
                       )
                   )
           );

           // Retrieve access token information
           $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

           // Native PHP object, please
           $token = json_decode($response);

           // Store access token and expiration time
           $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
           $_SESSION['expires_in'] = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
           $_SESSION['expires_at'] = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time
           return true;
       }

       public function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
           $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
               'format' => 'json',
           );

           // Need to use HTTPS
           $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
           // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
           $context = stream_context_create(
                   array('http' =>
                       array('method' => $method,
                       )
                   )
           );


           // Hocus Pocus
           $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

           // Native PHP object, please
           return json_decode($response);
       }

   }

   /* End of file Linked.php */
   /* Location: ./application/libraries/linkedin.php */
   ```
2. Put all your Constants stuff in confin/constants.php

   ```
   define('API_KEY', 'Put Yoour API_KEY here');
   define('API_SECRET', 'Put Yoour API_SECRET here');
   define('REDIRECT_URI', 'Put Yoour REDIRECT_URI here');
   define('SCOPE', 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus r_contactinfo r_network');
   ```
3. Now the Controller

   ```
   class Profile extends CI_Controller {

       function __construct() {
           parent:: __construct();
           $this->load->library('linkedin'); // load library
           session_name('linkedin');
           session_start();
       }

       // linkedin login script
       function profile() {
           // OAuth 2 Control Flow
           if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
               // LinkedIn returned an error
               // load any error view here
               exit;
           } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
               // User authorized your application
               if ($_SESSION['state'] == $_GET['state']) {
                   // Get token so you can make API calls
                   $this->linkedin->getAccessToken();
               } else {

                   // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
                   exit;
               }
           } else {
               if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
                   // Token has expired, clear the state
                   $_SESSION = array();
               }
               if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
                   // Start authorization process
                   $this->linkedin->getAuthorizationCode();
               }
           }
           // define the array of profile fields
           $profile_fileds = array(
               'id',
               'firstName',
               'maiden-name',
               'lastName',
               'picture-url',
               'email-address',
               'location:(country:(code))',
               'industry',
               'summary',
               'specialties',
               'interests',
               'public-profile-url',
               'last-modified-timestamp',
               'num-recommenders',
               'date-of-birth',
           );
           $profileData = $this->linkedin->fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(' . implode(',', $profile_fileds) . ')');
           if ($profileData) {
               // save profile or do whatever you want
           } else {
              // linked return an empty array of profile data
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for contributing this code. I will test it out and get right back to you.

Comment: I used this code.. but when i am trying to store $profileData in sesion it does not works..please help