# how to fetch linkedin data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

I am using codeigniter and want to fetch linkedin data but it not works.. it getting no error but i could not fetch data also
i am using this code defined in following url:

[Linkedin php api not setting access token in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497889/linkedin-php-api-not-setting-access-token-in-codeigniter)

and codes are

create library:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Linkedin {

    function __construct(){

    }

    public function getAuthorizationCode() {
        $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'scope' => SCOPE,
            'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
        // Authentication request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

        // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
        $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

        // Redirect user to authenticate
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

     public function getAccessToken() {
        $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
        // Access Token request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

        // Tell streams to make a POST request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => 'POST',
                    )
                )
        );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        // Native PHP object, please
        $token = json_decode($response);

        // Store access token and expiration time
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
        $_SESSION['expires_in'] = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
        $_SESSION['expires_at'] = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time
        return true;
    }

    public function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
        $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
            'format' => 'json',
        );

        // Need to use HTTPS
        $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => $method,
                    )
                )
        );


        // Hocus Pocus
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        // Native PHP object, please
        return json_decode($response);
    }

}
```

> Put all your Constants stuff in confin/constants.php
>
> ```
> define('API_KEY', 'Put Yoour API_KEY here');
> define('API_SECRET', 'Put Yoour API_SECRET here');
> define('REDIRECT_URI', 'Put Yoour REDIRECT_URI here');
> define('SCOPE', 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus r_contactinfo r_network');
> ```

and finally make my controller

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->library('linkedin'); // load library
        session_name('linkedin');
        session_start();
    }

    // linkedin login script
    function profile() {
        // OAuth 2 Control Flow
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            // LinkedIn returned an error
            // load any error view here
            exit;
        } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            // User authorized your application
            if ($_SESSION['state'] == $_GET['state']) {
                // Get token so you can make API calls
                $this->linkedin->getAccessToken();
            } else {

                // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
                // Token has expired, clear the state
                $_SESSION = array();
            }
            if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
                // Start authorization process
                $this->linkedin->getAuthorizationCode();
            }
        }
        // define the array of profile fields
        $profile_fileds = array(
            'id',
            'firstName',
            'maiden-name',
            'lastName',
            'picture-url',
            'email-address',
            'location:(country:(code))',
            'industry',
            'summary',
            'specialties',
            'interests',
            'public-profile-url',
            'last-modified-timestamp',
            'num-recommenders',
            'date-of-birth',
        );
        $profileData = $this->linkedin->fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(' . implode(',', $profile_fileds) . ')');
        if ($profileData) {
          $this->session->set_userdata("profile_session",$profileData);
        } else {
           // linked return an empty array of profile data
        }
    }

}
```

When i am running this controller then linkedin api works a modal window appears with my app name ..but after login
When i trying to print this session it does not apppears... dont know this code is working or not.. please help

Comment: codeingniter provvides a library called session, you should use that module, a detailed documentation can be found here: [Session Class CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

LinkedIn Class:

```
class Linkedin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->library('session'); 
    }


    public function getAuthorizationCode() {
        $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'scope' => SCOPE,
            'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
        // Authentication request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

        // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
        $this->session->set_userdata('state',$params['state']);

        // Redirect user to authenticate
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

     public function getAccessToken() {
        $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
        // Access Token request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

        // Tell streams to make a POST request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => 'POST',
                    )
                )
        );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        // Native PHP object, please
        $token = json_decode($response);

        // Store access token and expiration time
        $ses_params = array('access_token' => $token->access_token,
                            'expires_in' => $token->expires_in,
                            'expires_at' => time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']);
        $this->session->set_userdata($ses_params);
        return true;
    }

    public function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
        $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
            'format' => 'json',
        );

        // Need to use HTTPS
        $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => $method,
                    )
                )
        );


        // Hocus Pocus
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        // Native PHP object, please
        return json_decode($response);
    }

}
```

Profile Controller:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->library('linkedin'); // load library
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    // linkedin login script
    function profile() {
        // OAuth 2 Control Flow
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            // LinkedIn returned an error
            // load any error view here
            exit;
        } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            // User authorized your application
            if ($this->session->userdata('state'); == $_GET['state']) {
                // Get token so you can make API calls
                $this->linkedin->getAccessToken();
            } else {

                // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            if ((empty($this->session->userdata('expires_at'))) || (time() > $this->session->userdata('expires_at'))) {
                // Token has expired, clear the state
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
            }
            if (empty($this->session->userdata('access_token'))) {
                // Start authorization process
                $this->linkedin->getAuthorizationCode();
            }
        }
        // define the array of profile fields
        $profile_fileds = array(
            'id',
            'firstName',
            'maiden-name',
            'lastName',
            'picture-url',
            'email-address',
            'location:(country:(code))',
            'industry',
            'summary',
            'specialties',
            'interests',
            'public-profile-url',
            'last-modified-timestamp',
            'num-recommenders',
            'date-of-birth',
        );
        $profileData = $this->linkedin->fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(' . implode(',', $profile_fileds) . ')');
        if ($profileData) {
          $this->session->set_userdata("profile_session",$profileData);
        } else {
           // linked return an empty array of profile data
        }
    }

}
```